# Realm error: Your Realm is opened from a thread without a Looper and you provided a callback, we need a Handler to invoke your callback

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, rx-java

I've made this code in the method `onComplete()` of the subscriber:

```
long size, perc;
    public void onCompleted()
    {
        Log.wtf("on complete","On complete");
        realm = Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig);
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm mRealm) {
                AirportR airport = new AirportR();

                size = airp.size();
                Log.d("size:", String.valueOf(size));

                for (int i = 0; i < airp.size(); i++)
                {
                    airport.setId(Integer.parseInt(airp.get(i).getId()));

                    perc = i / size * 100;
                    Log.d("i + percentage", String.valueOf(i) + " - " + String.valueOf(perc));

                    mRealm.insertOrUpdate(airport);
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess()
            {
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

and when I use debugger, I see this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Your Realm is opened from a thread without a Looper and you provided a callback, we need a Handler to invoke your callback
```

and I see that if I don't use `Transaction.Success()` and `Transaction.OnError()` it works good and I have only this problem if I use these.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onCompleted()` doesn't seem to run on the UI thread. A normal background thread on a scheduler doesn't have a looper, so Realm cannot notify it when an async transaction is complete.

You should either use `executeTransaction()` because you're already on a background thread, or just run `executeTransactionAsync()` from a looper thread (for example the UI thread).

Comment: thanks...I also found the solution using this: getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    ... async here } }

Comment: Both works. Synchronous transaction makes sense if you are certain this always runs on a background thread.